# .NET CORE 6 dependency Injection error in attempt to register services along with MediatorR

Tags: c#, mediator, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on .NET CORE 6 Web API application and have implemented mediatorR. I am getting error. The mediatorR registration on its own does work but through issue when I am try to register other services i.e. `AddScoped<ISiteEntity, SiteEntity>()` I have also tried with AddTransient and still getting error

`error`

```
System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Txn.Application.UseCases.Sites.Queries.GetSite,Txn.Application.WrapperDTOs.SiteWrapperDataView] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Txn.Application.UseCases.Sites.Handlers.GetSiteHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'Txn.Domain.Interfaces.Queries.IGetSiteQuery' while attempting to activate 'Txn.Domain.Entities.SiteEntity'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Txn.Domain.Interfaces.Entities.ISiteEntity Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Txn.Domain.Entities.SiteEntity': Unable to resolve service for type 'Txn.Domain.Interfaces.Queries.IGetSiteQuery' while attempting to activate 'Txn.Domain.Entities.SiteEntity'.)'
```

`Handler`

```
public class GetSiteHandler : IRequestHandler<GetSite, SiteWrapperDataView>
{
    private readonly ISiteEntity _siteEntity;

    public GetSiteHandler(
        ISiteEntity siteEntity
        )
    {
        _siteEntity = siteEntity;
    }

    public async Task<SiteWrapperDataView> Handle(GetSite request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var siteData = await _siteEntity.GetSite(request.SiteId);

        var siteOutput = new SiteWrapperDataView
        {
            ResultSummary = siteData.Item2,
            Site = siteData.Item1
        };

        return siteOutput;
    }
}
```

`Program`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(ApplicationMediatorStartUp).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

//Domain
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISiteEntity, SiteEntity>();

//Queries
//builder.Services.AddTransient<IGetSiteQuery, GetSiteQuery>();

var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: you have not registered GetSiteHandler or some requested services from constructor arent registered

Comment: does not it should be covered by builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(ApplicationMediatorStartUp).GetTypeInfo().Assembly); since it is part of mediator

Comment: show the full exception.

Comment: I have updated error session up in question

Comment: The error tells you, that it cannot resolve `Txn.Domain.Interfaces.Queries.IGetSiteQuery`. Can you please add this interface and the concrete implementation?